# Migración proyecto de Python a C++

Tags: python, c++, linux, migration, gtk

estoy en el medio de una migración de un proyecto en **Python** a **C++** (Por tema de performance) El problema es que hay algunas librerias de **Python** (**GTK** para ser mas especifico) Que no tienen un equivalente en **GTKMM** (la version de **GTK** para **C++**) O al menos eso entiendo:

Hoy quería pedir una mano para poder entender como migrar esto y poder continuar con el proyecto. Desde ya muchas gracias a todos los que colaboran y dan una mano.

A continuación voy dejando lo que tengo en **Python** que no pude migrar por el momento:

```py
import gi
import json
from functools import lru_cache
gi.require_version('GMenu', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GMenu, Gio
import Lynx.Icons as icons

class Get:
    def __init__(self):
        self.menu_path = "/etc/xdg/menus/lynx-applications.menu"

    def build(self, menu=None, iteration=0, category=None, output={}):
        it = menu.iter()
        it_type = it
        while it_type is not GMenu.TreeItemType.INVALID:
            if it_type is GMenu.TreeItemType.DIRECTORY:

                item = it.get_directory()
                category = item.get_name()
                #dump(categorie, iteration)
                output[f'{category}'] = {}
                output[f'{category}']['icon'] = icons.get(item.get_icon().get_names()[0])
                output[f'{category}']['description'] = item.get_comment()
                output[f'{category}']['apps'] = []
                self.build(item, iteration + 1, category, output)

            elif it_type is GMenu.TreeItemType.ENTRY:

                item = it.get_entry()
                app = item.get_app_info()
                icon = app.get_icon()

                if isinstance(icon, Gio.ThemedIcon):
                    icon = icon.get_names()[0]
                elif isinstance(icon, Gio.FileIcon):
                    icon = icon.get_file().get_path()

                #dump(name, iteration+1)
                output[f'{category}']['apps'].append({
                    'category': f'{category}',
                    'name': f'{app.get_display_name()}',
                    'generic': f'{app.get_generic_name()}',
                    'description': f'{app.get_description()}',
                    'icon': f'{icons.get(icon)}',
                    'keywords': f'{" ".join(app.get_keywords())}',
                    'path': f'{item.get_desktop_file_path()}'
                    })

            it_type = it.next()

        return output

    @lru_cache(maxsize=200)
    def items(self):
        tree = GMenu.Tree.new_for_path(self.menu_path, 0)
        tree.load_sync()
        directory = tree.get_root_directory()
        menu = self.build(directory)
        return menu
```

En este caso por ejemplo no existe *GMenu.Tree* y no encontre una forma de obtener todos los elementos del Menu (Linux) para generar el **JSON**.

> El código en este caso busca en GNOME Menu todas las aplicaciones del menú y me genera un tree que luego lo paso a un JSON. El objetivo final es poder obtener todos las categorías y elementos del menú.

```py
import os, gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from functools import lru_cache as cache


def not_found(icon):
    print(f"Icon not found:{icon}")
    return "image-missing"

@cache(maxsize=None)
def get(icon: str) -> str:
    """
    :param icon:
    :return: icon name and path
    """
    if icon is None:
        icon = not_found(icon)

    EXTENSIONS = (".png", ".svg", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif")
    if icon.endswith(EXTENSIONS):
        # if image has full icon path return icon.
        if icon.startswith("/"):
            return icon
        # if image has icon name and extension, but no path.
        else:
            for ext in EXTENSIONS:
                if icon.endswith(ext):
                    icon = icon.replace(ext, '')

    icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
    if not icon_theme.has_icon(icon):
        # check for icon in pixmaps directory.
        pixmaps = f"/usr/share/pixmaps/{icon}"
        for ext in EXTENSIONS:
            if os.path.isfile(f"{pixmaps}{ext}"):
                return f"{pixmaps}{ext}"

    SIZES = (64, 48, 32, 24)
    for size in SIZES:
        icon_name = icon_theme.lookup_icon(icon, size, 0)
        if icon_name:
            return icon_name.get_filename()

    icon = not_found(icon)
    return icon
```

En este caso no pude obtener el *Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()* que me permite buscar los iconos del en el theme en uso.

> En este caso el código me permite obtener el PATH de un icono, revisa si tiene o no extensión, si lo que le di ya es un path y en el caso de no ser un path lo busca entre los iconos del icon theme instalado en linux

Muchas gracias por todo y estoy a su entera disposición.

Comment: Creo que seria mas fácil explicar lo que hace el código asi se podría hallar el equivalente, además las personas que sepan de c++ y no de Python podrán entender mejor

Comment: @Christian Gracias por comentar, ahí actualice la publicación agregando lo que deberían hacer (Es verdad por ahí no es replicar el código es buscar la mejor forma de obtener eso) Realmente muchas gracias!

Comment: Como recomendación general, si la razón de pasar de Python a C++ es la performance, yo te diría que intentes antes otras cosas. Por ejemplo, ejecutar con pypy en vez de con python "normal" (si es posible). O escribir en C solamente las partes más críticas (haciendo antes un _profiling_ para averiguar cuáles son), o usar Cython para esto. La interfaz de usuario normalmente no suele ser crítica, a menos que se trate de un videojuego o algo así en tiempo real.

Comment: No pasa solo por la performance, Estamos cambiando el backend por un proyecto llamado neutralino JS, El mismo maneja de mejor forma el binding entre el browser y c++ que lo que tenemos armado, esto nos permite expandir mejor el poryecto. Actualmente lo que mantenemos en Python mezcla QT usa Chromiun como browser y eso no implica mucho consumo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comento que la solución en esta ocasiona fue mantener python para ejecutar y procesar el menú. dado que la ganancia no es tan amplia como para migrarlo simplemente mantenemos python para algunas funcionalidades dividiendo el proyecto en componentes mas pequeños.